# Need to finding overlapping dates in XML code

Tags: xpath, schematron

I need help finding the overlapping dates in this XML code. I need to make sure that the End date is not less than or equal to the proceeding Start Date.

```
       <Inventory>
          <StatusApplicationControl Start="2019-07-18" End="2019-07-18" InvTypeCode="STDX" />
          <InvCounts>
            <InvCount CountType="2" Count="9" />
          </InvCounts>
        </Inventory>
        <Inventory>
          <StatusApplicationControl Start="2019-07-18" End="2019-07-19" InvTypeCode="STDX" />
          <InvCounts>
            <InvCount CountType="2" Count="8" />
          </InvCounts>
        </Inventory>
```

I have tried the following code.

```
<rule context="Inventory">
            <report test="translate(StatusApplicationControl/@Start, '-', '') &lt;= translate(preceding::Inventory/preceding::StatusApplicationControl/@End, '-', '')">The @Start="<value-of select="@Start"/>" and @End="<value-of select="@End"/>" dates are overlaping</report>
</rule>
```

I expect this message to be printed -
The Start="2019-07-18" is less than or equal to the End="2019-07-18" date

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear what it's your actual output. Beside that, it looks like your message use the `Start` and `End` attributes from the same context.

Comment: Thanks Alejandro, I changed the above code and now it works but I can't get the values of the Start and End dates. If I figure this out I'll post the answer.

Comment: If your are comparing `StatusApplicationControl/@Start` and `preceding::Inventory/preceding::StatusApplicationControl/@End`, why your message is using `@Start` and `@End`?

Comment: Because those values can only come from the context. So for those values to be picked up the context would have to be `context="Inventory/StatusApplicationControl" `

Comment: But you want the "other" `@End` attribute...

Comment: I want to compare the `@End` attribute above to the `@Start` attribute below. The `@Start` date should not be less than or equal to the above `@End` date.

Comment: What is your `queryBinding`? Does your Schematron-Engine support XSLT 2 or 3?

Comment: Hi Nico, I using a .Net Schematron console app compiled with Xpath 2.0

Comment: I don't have any experiances with that Schematron implementation, but in XPath 2.0 I would suggest something like `xs:date(StatusApplicationControl/@Start) &lt;= xs:date(preceding::Inventory[1]/StatusApplicationControl/@End)`. However, according to your comment of Alejandros answer, the implementation seems not really stable, because I can not see any bad in that answer and it works on my implementation (Oxygen).

Comment: Thanks Nico, just want to add that it's this that Schematron dosn't like `select="preceding::Inventory[1]/StatusApplicationControl/@End"
    />"` when I remove that the rule is good.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the comments are not helping you.

The rule should be:

```
<rule context="Inventory">
   <report 
      test="translate(StatusApplicationControl/@Start, '-', '') 
            &lt;=translate(preceding::Inventory[1]/StatusApplicationControl/@End,'-','')"
   >The @Start="<value-of select="@Start"/>" and @End="<value-of 
    select="preceding::Inventory[1]/StatusApplicationControl/@End"
    />" dates are overlaping</report>
</rule>
```

**EDIT**

This Schematron

```
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron">
  <pattern>
    <title>Test dates</title>
    <rule context="Inventory">
      <assert 
      test="translate(StatusApplicationControl/@Start, '-', '') 
            > translate(preceding::Inventory[1]/StatusApplicationControl/@End,'-','')"
      >The @Start="<value-of 
       select="StatusApplicationControl/@Start"
       />" and @End="<value-of 
       select="preceding::Inventory[1]/StatusApplicationControl/@End"
       />" dates are overlaping</assert>
    </rule>
  </pattern>
</schema>
```

With this input:

```
<root> 
    <Inventory>
          <StatusApplicationControl Start="2019-07-18" End="2019-07-18" InvTypeCode="STDX" />
          <InvCounts>
            <InvCount CountType="2" Count="9" />
          </InvCounts>
        </Inventory>
        <Inventory>
          <StatusApplicationControl Start="2019-07-18" End="2019-07-19" InvTypeCode="STDX" />
          <InvCounts>
            <InvCount CountType="2" Count="8" />
          </InvCounts>
        </Inventory>
  </root>
```

Output:

```
Pattern 'Test dates' Failed : The @Start="2019-07-18" and @End="2019-07-18" dates are overlaping.
```

Check in https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-schematron-validator

Comment: Thanks Alejandro, But I get a Schematron Exception when I use that rule. passing anything other `@End` causes the exception. When remove `preceding::Inventory[1]/StatusApplicationControl` from the `select` it works.

Comment: Hi Alejandro, The above rule only works with 2 `Inventory` blocks how do I make it work with more? thanks!

Comment: Thanks Alejandro, I guess it's the difference in Schematron engines. I'm using this https://github.com/gap777/SchemaTron and your rule dosn't work with it. I thought all implementations would be the same, but I guess not. Again thanks for your help!

Comment: Your Schematron engine uses XPath 2.0.- The only way that this expression `translate(preceding::Inventory[1]/StatusApplicationControl/@End,'-','')` reports an error is because you have many `StatusApplicationControl` for each `Inventory`, something that your input sample doesn't show.

Comment: Hi Alejandro, Yes I'm using XPath 2.0 but as my example shows I only have one `StatusApplicationControl for each Inventory` so not sure if this is because I use  .NET Schematon or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SchemaTron rule that worked for me. The issue was passing `preceding::` to the translate() function. When doing that I got a SchemaTron Exception.

```
<rule context="Inventory/StatusApplicationControl">
            <report test="translate(@Start, '-', '') &lt;= preceding::StatusApplicationControl/translate(@End, '-', '')  ">The @Start="<value-of select="@Start"/>" and @End="<value-of select="@End"/>" dates are overlaping</report>
        </rule>
```

Comment: Beware that this expression `preceding::StatusApplicationControl/translate(@End, '-', '')` is not XPath 1.0 and that in XPath 2.0 it would result into an existential comparison with all the preceding (any level) `@End` atributes.

Comment: Yes, I need it to compare all the preceding values and I never know how many there will be. +1 for pointing out that it's the difference in XPath versions!